# How to configure .ycm_extra_conf.py for current project include PATH

Tags: c, vim, makefile, clang, youcompleteme

I installed YCM and syntastic for VIM, normally they work fine, but I have problem when it detect some errors in my code, it shows that can NOT find some head files(which is my project head file).

My directory tree shows below:

```
TOP
├── debug
│   ├── debug.c
│   ├── debug.h
│   ├── debug.mk
│   └── instrument.c
├── driver
│   ├── driver.c
│   ├── driver_ddi.c
│   ├── driver_ddi.h
│   ├── driver.h
│   └── driver.mk
├── include
│   └── common.h
├── libs
├── Makefile
├── mw
│   ├── manager.c
│   └── mw.mk
└── root
    ├── main.c
    └── root.mk
```

I copied a `.ycm_extra_conf.py` to the TOP, meanwhile, I will generated `tag` and `cscope` file at TOP as well, therefore each time I open file on TOP, like:

```
howchen@host:~/Work/c/sample/src
-> gvim ./driver/driver.c
```

to make sure each time I can add `tag` and `cscope` file in VIM. The problem is, if I open `driver.c`, which contain head files： `driver.h`, `driver_ddi.h`, `debug.h`, `common.h`, code like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "math.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "debug.h"
#include "driver_ddi.h"
#include "driver.h"
```

the `syntastic` or `YCM` always show it can NOT find `common.h` and `debug.h`, other head files are OK.

**My YCM and syntastic config part in vimrc file:**

```
" YCM
"   let g:ycm_extra_conf_globlist = ['~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/cpp/ycm/*','!~/*']
    let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py'

" Syntastic
    let g:syntastic_c_checkers=['make']
    let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
    let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1
    let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
    let g:syntastic_error_symbol = '✗'
    let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = '⚠'
    set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
    set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
    set statusline+=%*gbar
```

**My `.ycm_extra_conf.py` write `flags` variable as:**

```
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-Wextra',
'-Werror',
'-Wc++98-compat',
'-Wno-long-long',
'-Wno-variadic-macros',
'-fexceptions',
'-DNDEBUG',
'-std=c99',
# ...and the same thing goes for the magic -x option which specifies the
# language that the files to be compiled are written in. This is mostly
# relevant for c++ headers.
# For a C project, you would set this to 'c' instead of 'c++'.
'-x', #I don't know if I need remove -x
'c',
'-isystem',
'../llvm/include',
'-isystem',
'../llvm/tools/clang/include',
'-I',
'.',
'-I',
'../driver'
'-I',
'../debug'
'-I',
'../include'
'-I',
'../include'
]
```

any wrong flags I set?

Comment: Again, try their issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl, I tried, but no reply

Comment: What is the symptom when Syntastic cannot find the header files?

Comment: @benjifisher, just show can NOT file `xxx` head file in my location windows in VIM

Comment: The `flags` variable is irrelevant. The return value of the `FlagsForFile` function is. How do you postprocess the flags? What does it return? Specifically, does it involve converting `-I` arguments to absolute paths (see [this function in ycm's own config](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/master/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py#L118-L144))?

Comment: missing comma on the 4th line from the bottom

Comment: @Tosha, after I add this comma, still doesn't work, the missing file exist in `../include`, not `../debug`, but anyway, thanks for pointing this error.

Comment: Can you add a link to the issue on github?

Comment: Did you found anything?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal, not yet, still checking

Comment: @HowChen , this is how I do it. First compile program using clang++ , not g++ and use cmake to export compilation database. Then set the absolute path to compilation database in your ycm_extra....conf. Most likely it will be the build directory , because compilation database changes each time you build with file/directory changes.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal, thanks for your comment, the problem is, on my SW work farm, it always use `gcc/g++` to compile the program, what is the main diff between `clang++` and `gcc` during compilation?

Comment: YCM is clang dependent :)

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal, yes, I know YCM need be compiled by `clang`, but the project or code I'm working on is not `clang` dependent, as I understanding is, after I compiled YCM, it should be used for my normal project, am I right?

Comment: No , YCM still uses clang's compile flag to provide C++ autocomplete feature. that is why you need to build your project with clang.

Comment: if your .ycm_extra_conf.py is at top dir, you debug path should be ./debug, not ../debug. ycm use relative path base on the .ycm_extra_conf.py file path.

Comment: why dont you use a ycm-generator? you could try that and look what config file it outputs: https://github.com/rdnetto/YCM-Generator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Moved here from the question.*

I found the problem:

```
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-Wextra',
'-Werror',
'-Wc++98-compat',
'-Wno-long-long',
'-Wno-variadic-macros',
'-fexceptions',
'-DNDEBUG',
'-std=c99',
# ...and the same thing goes for the magic -x option which specifies the
# language that the files to be compiled are written in. This is mostly
# relevant for c++ headers.
# For a C project, you would set this to 'c' instead of 'c++'.
'-x', #I don't know if I need remove -x
'c',
'-isystem',
'../llvm/include',
'-isystem',
'../llvm/tools/clang/include',
'-I./driver',
'-I./debug',
'-I./include',
]
```

I missed a comma and path should be `./xxx`, also neeeeed `'-I/usr/include'`, and `'-I/usr/local/include'`.